# How do I prevent repeat code for handling forms in views.py using decorators?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, python-decorators

### Context

I'm handling a form in a python view. Basic stuff.

```
def index(request):

    # Handle form.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Do stuff
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thankyou/')
    else:
        form = CustomForm()

    # Render.
    context = RequestContext(request, {
            'form':form,
        })
    return render_to_response('app/index.html', context)
```

This form is shown on multiple pages, and I've ended up having duplicates of the form-handling code in multiple functions in views.py, rendering different templates. (However, the template code for the form resides in the base template)

That's dumb, so I tried looking around for ways to prevent the repeat of code. I like the suggested use of python decorators in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482525/django-tips-to-avoid-repeating-code-in-views) Stackoverflow question. I also found an excellent explanation of python's decorators [here](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/python-decorators/).

### Question

I'm having trouble with trying to write the decorator. I need to return a form after the first `if` statement, followed by executing another `if` statement. But in a python function, no code after a `return` function gets executed... Does this require something like a nested decorator..?

Suggestions? Non-decorator suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer to your main question but this info may be helpful to you or somebody.

The question with suggestion about decorators is pretty old. Started from 1.3 version django have [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) - i think this is what you are looking for. By subclassing views you can reduce duplication of code (code from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/) just for example):

```
# Base view
class MyFormView(View):
    form_class = MyForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'form_template.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # <process form cleaned data>
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Now you can create another views classes based on `MyFormView` view. Form processing code stays same, but you can change it of course:

```
class AnotherView(MyFormView):
    form_class = AnotherForm
    initial = {'key1': 'value1'}
    template_name = 'form1_template.html'

    # you dont need to redefine post here if code stays same,
    # post from base class will be used
```

Comment: Well, it seems to me that subclassing views only allows me to specify the model data that I want present in my view, rather than do something like handle a form. Might you be able to show me how I could handle a form using class based views?

Comment: Ah. I was reading the documentation for class based views for version 1.3, not realizing that they had added in support for forms since 1.5. I guess I'll have to finally switch up then. Sorry, but I won't mark it as the answer as it really isn't the answer to the question. Upvoted though!