# Django, how to reuse views code in other views and template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I'm new in django and I was wondering if is it possible to reuse code and annotate output write in a views.py.

I have created a lot of new annotate output that I want to reuse to figure out a dashboard with graphs and key indicator. I don't like to rewrite all code because I wouldn't follow the DRY principles.

Ad example I have the following views, what is the best way to reuse this code in other views?

```
def conto_economico(request):
    # Creazione tabella materie prime, sussidiarie, di consumo e merci
    defaults = list(0 for m in range(12))
    elements = dict()
    for conto_id, year, month, totale in(Materiale.objects.values_list('conto__nome', 'data__year', 'data__month').annotate(totale=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('quantita') * F('prezzo')),
        output_field=FloatField())).values_list('conto__nome', 'data__year', 'data__month', 'totale').order_by("conto_id")) :
        if conto_id not in elements.keys():
            elements[conto_id]=list(defaults)
        index=month-1
        elements[conto_id][index]=totale

    total_elements={'Per materie prime, sussidiarie, di consumo e di merci': [sum(t) for t in zip(*elements.values())],}

    context= {
        'elements': elements,
        'total_elements':total_elements,
    }

    return render(request, 'conto_economico/conto_economico.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For views.py file, it's a good idea to use decorators. Further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482525/django-tips-to-avoid-repeating-code-in-views) in another question.

For templates, use the `{% include %}` tag. For example, you can write snippets of code in another document (eg. HTML) and just pluggin that code within another template using the `{% include '_example.html' %}` template tag. In this case the other file is named `_example.html`.

**Edit 1:**

To use the same context in other functions' templates, what we need to do is create a `context_processor.py` file within that particular Django app. It's a Django convention. Context Processors are handy when we need to make something available globally to all templates across all Django apps.

Context Processor usually returns a dictionary that gets added to the `request` context.

Your code will looks something like this conceptually, you may need to debug the code for errors-

```
# <app_name>/context_processor.py (this is the same folder where the views.py)

from .models import Materiale

def conto_economico(request):
    # Creazione tabella materie prime, sussidiarie, di consumo e merci
    defaults = list(0 for m in range(12))
    elements = dict()
    for conto_id, year, month, totale in(Materiale.objects.values_list('conto__nome', 'data__year', 'data__month').annotate(totale=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('quantita') * F('prezzo')),
        output_field=FloatField())).values_list('conto__nome', 'data__year', 'data__month', 'totale').order_by("conto_id")) :
        if conto_id not in elements.keys():
            elements[conto_id]=list(defaults)
        index=month-1
        elements[conto_id][index]=totale

    total_elements={'Per materie prime, sussidiarie, di consumo e di merci': [sum(t) for t in zip(*elements.values())],}

    #context= {
        #'elements': elements,
        #'total_elements':total_elements,
    #}

    #return render(request, 'conto_economico/conto_economico.html', context)
    return dict(elements=elements, total_elements=total_elements)
```

Considerations-

- I've never used more than one variable in the `dict()` within a `context_processor.py`. In this case we're passing two. You may need to look out for any error.

And then make this context available in the `settings.py` file of the project-

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'app_name.context_processors.conto_economico', # change the 'app_name' to the actual app name.
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now the two context variables `elements` and `total_elements` should be available to all templates. It no longer required to copy paste the code of `def conto_economico` function in other functions within views.py.

Further reading- https://dev.to/harveyhalwin/using-context-processor-in-django-to-create-dynamic-footer-45k4

Comment: @F A thanks for your answer. I have really appreciated your answer but I don't knwo if is the best way to figure out my needs. I have added in the question a snippets of my views code, to better explain my needs.

Comment: do you want to reuse the entire function `conto_economico` or certain portion? if certain portion, which portion do u want to reuse?

Comment: I want to reuse only the context results, becouse this views give me a table, and I want to create another views to figure out a dashboard with graphs utilizing the same context

Comment: @FedericoDeMarco I've updated the answer. One more thing to keep into mind about using Context Processors, use it as less as possible as it puts load on the `request`.